# Wikipedia - Retrive English name from German link

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am trying to retrieve some Wikipedia informations using [mediawiki api](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page). I am trying to retrieve information of "Helmuth Johannes Ludwig von Moltke"

```
English link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmuth_von_Moltke_the_Younger
German link: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmuth_Johannes_Ludwig_von_Moltke
```

In this two links the title (name of person) is different.

I am using mediawiki english api link to retrieve some info. So if I pass english name to [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&rvprop=content&rvlimit=1&titles=Helmuth_von_Moltke_the_Younger) it is working fine. But not with german name [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&rvprop=content&rvlimit=1&titles=Helmuth_Johannes_Ludwig_von_Moltke).

If I pass German name to german API [link](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&rvprop=content&rvlimit=1&titles=Helmuth_Johannes_Ludwig_von_Moltke), it will retrieve data. But at that time I cannot perform any English string search to retrive data.

So is there any way to find the actual English name/link from a German link.

Please let me know if there is any other solution for this problem.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the name of the German article, you can use the `langlinks` module of the German Wikipedia API to retrieve the language links of the article (including the English one):

https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Helmuth_Johannes_Ludwig_von_Moltke&prop=langlinks&lllimit=max

If you only want the English link, use `lllang=en`:

https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Helmuth_Johannes_Ludwig_von_Moltke&prop=langlinks&lllang=en